# Exception in thread “main” java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, regex

De la línea

```
D:\\csv\rssi_data_upload_00_11_74_86_49_7F_1519231770
```

necesito ejecutar la expresión regular

```
upload_(.+)_[0-9]+
```

para así obtener el valor de `00_11_74_86_49_7F`.

Este es mi código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{

  String query_MAC_AP="upload_(.+)_[0-9]+";
  Pattern pmacap = Pattern.compile(query_MAC_AP);
  Matcher mmacap=pmacap.matcher("D:\\csv\rssi_data_upload_00_11_74_86_49_7F_1519231770");
  mmacap.matches();
  String mac_AP=mmacap.group(1);
  System.out.println(mac_AP);
}
```

Cada vez que lo ejecuto me aparece el siguiente error

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
> at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Unknown Source)
> at tfc.Main.main(Main.java:30)
> ```

¿Qué tengo mal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found at java.util.regex.Matcher.group

Es un error que se da porque:

- El regex no coincide
- Luego estás intentando referenciar a `Matcher#group()`, el texto capturado por una coincidencia que no existe!

---

**¿Por qué no coincide?**

Porque el método [Matcher#matches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--) intenta coincidir con **TODO** el texto (el texto desde el principio hasta el fin), y claramente no es el caso de tu regex... Además, siempre deberías utilizar un `if`/`while` para ver si coincidió antes de referenciar el resultado de una coincidencia.

Para ejecutar un regex sobre cualquier posición de un texto se usa el método [**Matcher#find()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--).

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// Buscar la primera coincidencia del regex
// (o usar un while para buscar todas)

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Coincide con: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Grupo " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Te conviene usar siempre `Matcher#find()` y olvidarte de `matches()`. Para buscar una coincidencia en todo el texto con `find()`, basta con anclarlo a `^` y `$` (o en realidad a `\A` y `\z`).

Comment: Perfecto!!! Funciona correctamente.